# How to have a different logo on mobile view wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

How can i show a different logo when my website is viewed on a mobile device?

I know nothing about html for after some research i found that this can be done adding some ccs to my style.ccs.

Im working on Wordpress but i tryed different ways and no one worked for me. If anyone can help me with a code for my web im going to be very grateful :)

My web is camporecoleta.com.ar and i want to show the next logo when the page is loaded on a mobile device: http://camporecoleta.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Logo-1-1.png

I hope anyone can help me, sorry if i had any mistake, my main language is not english

Answer (score 0):

Well there is probably a lot of ways to do it but one easy way would be plain old css with @media that will apply diffrent styling depending on the viewport.

Basicaly you could use a css background image on an element and when the screen gets to a specified size there is another css class with a diffrent image that is apply.

You could also just ajust the size of that same logo.

[CSS @media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CSS media queries` like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px)
{
     /* style here apply for screen width up to 640px */
     #logo
     {
         background-image: url('pathToImages/myMobileLogo.jpg');
     }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 640px)
{
     /* style here apply for screen width above 640px*/
     #logo
     {
         background-image: url('pathToImages/myBiggerImage.jpg');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue with media queries
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

or 
Try function `wp_is_moible()`

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile